# Vaadin 7: File Upload

Tags: vaadin7

I have a Upload component in which I´m supposed to import a xml file in order to parse it.

I´m trying to use the File.createTempFile method to create the file phisically,but something weird is going on.

For example,if I take the file named "test.xml" and use the createTempFile method to create it on the disk,the name of the generate file becomes something like 'test.xml13234xml'.How can I create the file the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected when using i.e. `createTempFile` method as it implicitly creates a file with random prefix:

```java
// a part of createTempFile method
private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
static File generateFile(String prefix, String suffix, File dir) {
    long n = random.nextLong();
    if (n == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
        n = 0;      // corner case
    } else {
        n = Math.abs(n);
    }
    return new File(dir, prefix + Long.toString(n) + suffix);
}
```

which should give something like 'test.xml13234xml'.

If you want to create a file with the correct name and keep it for later use you can rename/move it within `uploadSucceeded` method.

```java
public class ExampleUpload implements Upload.Receiver, Upload.SucceededListener {
    private Upload xmlUpload;
    private File tempFile;

    public ExampleUpload() {
        this.xmlUpload = new Upload("Upload:", this);
        this.xmlUpload.addSucceededListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
        try {
            tempFile = File.createTempFile(filename, "xml");
            tempFile.deleteOnExit();
            return new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
        try {
            File destinationFile = new File("c:\\" + event.getFilename());
            FileUtils.moveFile(tempFile, destinationFile));
            // TODO read and parse destinationFile
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```